# Python create permutation from list without duplicates

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, combinations, permutation

```
#Input
t = ['pid', 'sn', 'uuid', 'host_id']
# Expected output
[('pid'),('sn'),('uuid'),('host_id'),('pid','sn'),('pid','uuid'),('pid','host_id'),('sn','uuid'),('sn','host_id',('uid','host_id'))]
```

I want to extract single values first and then extract the combination without duplicates.

For e.g. `('pid','sn')` and `('sn','pid')` are same. I want only one value. I tried permutations in itertools but it is returning all the matches.

Comment: Try [`itertools.combinations()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `combinations` instead of `permutations`:

```
import itertools

t = ['pid', 'sn', 'uuid', 'host_id']
result = []
for n in range(1, len(t)+1):
    for res in itertools.combinations(t, n):
        result.append(res)
result
```

output:

```
[('pid',),
 ('sn',),
 ('uuid',),
 ('host_id',),
 ('pid', 'sn'),
 ('pid', 'uuid'),
 ('pid', 'host_id'),
 ('sn', 'uuid'),
 ('sn', 'host_id'),
 ('uuid', 'host_id'),
 ('pid', 'sn', 'uuid'),
 ('pid', 'sn', 'host_id'),
 ('pid', 'uuid', 'host_id'),
 ('sn', 'uuid', 'host_id'),
 ('pid', 'sn', 'uuid', 'host_id')]
```